# Oracle: Get Results based on most recent timestamp

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, greatest-n-per-group

You can only post once every 90 minutes.

Hi I have following tables.I am trying to get the `citi_id` which have most recent transaction in second table.

My first table `City` has `trip_id`, `citi_id` and `citi_name`.

In one trip, a person can travel to one or more cities one or more times. I am looking to get results where he went more than two cities on one trip and, if true get most recent timestamp one based on `time_visited` in the second table. If two timestamps are same for both cities get `citi` which have more visits, and if two cities have same number of visits get least `citi_id`.

```sql
Create table City(trip_id number(10),citi_id number(10),citi_name varchar2(40));
    
Create table City_Time(citi_id number(10),time_visited DATE);
    
    
Insert Into City values(1,17854,'Omaha');
Insert Into City values(1,27854,'Newyork')
Insert Into City values(2,37854,'Chicago');
Insert Into City values(2,47854,'Vegas')
Insert Into City values(2,57854,'Los Angels')
Insert Into City values(3,67854,'San Francisco');
    
Insert into City_Time(citi_id,time_visited)values(17854,TO_DATE('2015/05/15 8:30:25', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS'));
Insert into City_Time(citi_id,time_visited)values(27854,TO_DATE('2015/05/15 8:30:25', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS'));
Insert into City_Time(citi_id,time_visited)values(27854,TO_DATE('2015/05/20 8:30:25', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS'))
Insert into City_Time(citi_id,time_visited)values(37854,TO_DATE('2015/07/17 8:30:25', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS'))
Insert into City_Time(citi_id,time_visited)values(47854,TO_DATE('2015/07/17 8:30:25', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS'))
Insert into City_Time(citi_id,time_visited)values(57854,TO_DATE('2015/08/22 8:30:25', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS'))
Insert into City_Time(citi_id,time_visited)values(67854,TO_DATE('2015/09/31 8:30:25', 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS'))
```

Input: trip_id=1 true it have exactly two trips

Ouput: citi_id=27854

Input: trip_id=2 true it have exactly two trips

Ouput: citi_id=37854 because it is lowest.

Answer (score 0):

You can use analytic functions for this:

```sql
SELECT citi_id,
       time_visited
FROM   (
  SELECT t.citi_id,
         t.time_visited,
         COUNT( t.citi_id ) OVER( PARTITION BY trip_id ) AS num_cities,
         RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY trip_id ORDER BY time_visited DESC )
           AS time_rank
  FROM   city c
         INNER JOIN city_time t
         ON ( c.citi_id= t.citi_id )
)
WHERE  num_cities = 2
AND    time_rank = 1;
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> CITI_ID | TIME_VISITED       
> ------: | :------------------
>   27854 | 2015-05-20 08:30:25
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=294e88117532cd345658fcf9fb55a915)*

Comment: MT0...thanks for the answer slighlty modified the question